# Python reduce memory usage when passing class functions

Tags: python, class, memory-management

In my python code, I try to compute the material response of a structure consisting of two different materials.

After inspecting the code, I found that the following type of structure is using a lot of memory:

```
class ClassA:
    # This is a class with some memory expensive properties
    def __init__(self, prop_a, prop_b):
        self.prop_a = prop_a
        self.prop_b = prop_b
    # A function
    def calculateC(self, ka, kb):
        C = ka * kb # some long, expensive calculation going on here
    return C

class Communicator:
    # This is a class will need the function handles that point to calculateC
    def __init__(self, function1, function2):
        self.function1 = function1
        self.function2 = function2

    def splitComputeCompose(self, ka, kb, ind1, ind2):
        ans1 = self.function1(ka[ind1], kb[ind1]) # compute the part related to inst1
        ans2 = self.function1(ka[ind2], kb[ind2]) # compute the part related to inst2
        ans = [ans1, ans2] # compose the final array to return
    return ans

def main():
    part1 = ClassA(someValue1, someValue2)
    part2 = ClassA(someValue3, someValue4)

    myCommunicator = Communicator(part1.calculateC, part2.calculateC) # somehow doubles the memory usage
```

The problem, as far as I understand it, is that passing part1.calculateC & part2.calculateC to the communicator class seems to copy them.

How do I avoid this? How do I merely pass the function handle, is there a way to improve the above structure?

Comment: You are not copying objects in this code.  In Python a statement like a = b doesn't create a new object, it simply binds an existing object (named "b") to the name "a".  An object like `part1.calculateC` is a function object (somewhat similar to a function pointer in C) and has almost no memory overhead. Why do you think that this code is using a lot of memory?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paul. It turns out you are right, there is almost no memory overhead when passing the object 'part1.calculateC'. I must have looked wrong during the debug.